# How to declare axioms in Agda?

Tags: logic, algebra, agda

I was reading the book "Algebra driven design" and in the second chapter it starts designing a simple algebra system like this:

```
data Tile

haskell :: Tile
sandy :: Tile

cw :: Tile -> Tile

∀ (t :: Tile).
  cw (cw (cw (cw t))) = t
```

and it starts building up from there. So I thought it would be nice if I could use a proof assistant to follow along.

I saw someone do this with Coq [here](https://github.com/dbramucci/coq-proofs-algebra-driven-design/blob/master/chapter_2_1.v) and I thought surely it's possible to do in Agda too, but I don't know how to define an axiom like it is defined in the Coq example (`Axiom cw : Tile -> Tile.`).

Keep in mind that I'm not interested in actually implementing the functions here, I just need to do algebra based on some axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Agda equivalent of `Axiom` is [`postulate`](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/postulates.html), which should work basically the same way.